# Passing the values of DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have 2 Data Extensions.I use one data extension for sending email.In the email ,i have a link to the cloud page.But in the cloud page ,the values should be pre-populated ,where one of the rows have value from the 2nd Data Extension.There is a common field between these 2 Data Extension that is Customer ID.How do i pre-populate that value?

Comment: you need to populate the 2 data extension values when you click on submit button in email ?

Comment: probably answered here?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165040/using-ampscript-to-pre-populate-a-smart-capture-forms-in-salesforce-marketing-cl

Comment: i want to autopopulate the values in cloud pages...before clicking the submit button @pkharries

Comment: i mean after clicking link in receiving ur email  then only populate values in cloud page am i correct ?

Comment: YES..EXACTLY@pkharries

Answer (score 0):

@try like tthis

```
  %%[
      set @email=AttributeValue("emailaddr")

      set @recordID = lookuprows("DE2","Email",@email)

   if rowcount(@recordID)>0 then

      Set @row = ROW(@recordID,1)
       Set @act = FIELD(@row,"Name")
        Set @act1 = FIELD(@row,"count")  
        endif
       ]%%
      %%=v(@act)=%%
         <html>
        <body>
      <form id="my_form" method="post">


     <input type="text" name="test" value="%%=v(@act)=%%"/>
     <input type="text" name="test1" value="%%=v(@act1)=%%"/>
     <form>
      </body>
     </html>
```